# Plotting Contour

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot co Contour Plots for Tempereature data given in 2D Space (X,Z) in Mathematica. The data is read from CSV file. I have a code that I thinks should work fine, but it plots something outrages. Please help to correct my code. It is below

```
SetDirectory["G:\\FGCI Staff\\Madyarova\\Mathematica\\Contour Plots"];

dataContour = Import["DataToPlot 90.csv"];    
len = Length[dataContour];

TemeratureChange = dataContour[[2 ;; len, 11]];    
Zm = dataContour[[2 ;; len, 3]];
Xm = dataContour[[2 ;; len, 9]];    
data1 = Table[{ TemeratureChange[[i]], Xm[[i]], Zm[[i]]}, {i, 1, 
    len - 1}];    
ListContourPlot[Transpose[data1], PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 Contours -> 30, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x axis", "y axis"}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Temperature Change (oC)"]
```

This code plots this [image]

I am expecting to see contour plot similar to this [image]. 
The last picture was ploted in Grapher.

What is wring with Mathematica code above? Thank you.

Best wishes,
Maria

Comment: Have you looked at your data? What numbers correspond with the vertical black lines?

Comment: Without seeing the data, I'd expect that you want `{Xm[[i]], Zm[[i]], TemeratureChange[[i]]}` – the values corresponding to contours is #3 in the data.  But the use of Transpose is also confusing to me, since it looks like `data1` should already be the list of {x, y, z} triples the ListContourPlot wants.

Comment: Temperature is changing {from -3.8 to 2.6}. My X coordinate is changing within the range {-98 to 98 }. My Y coordinate is changing within the range {-5 to 235 }. I don't know exactly what black lines are

Comment: @MaryMadyarova I think this will help: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Once you do this please take a look at [asking guidelines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're doing something like

```
ListContourPlot[Transpose@
  Flatten[Table[{Sin[i + j^2], i, j}, {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}], 1]]
```

[image]

when you really want

```
ListContourPlot[Flatten[Table[{i, j, Sin[i + j^2]}, {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}], 1]]
```

[image]

With the transposed data, `ListContourPlot` treats it as an array of heights instead of `{x, y, z}` triples.

(You can ignore the `Flatten` in my code above, it's just there to get a list of triples instead of an 2D array of them.)

So I think what you're really looking for is

```
data1 = Table[{Xm[[i]], Zm[[i]], TemeratureChange[[i]]}, {i, 1, len - 1}];    
ListContourPlot[data1, <options>]
```

Comment: Brett Champion, I have changed the last two lines how you proposed and it looks better now. data1 = Table[{ Xm[[i]], Zm[[i]], TemeratureChange[[i]]}, {i, 1, len - 1}]; ListContourPlot[data1, PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> Hue, AxesLabel -> {"x axis", "y axis"}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotLabel -> "Temperature Change (oC)"] Do you know why I have this white color in the middle of the plot and why axis labels {"x", "y"} are not on the plot? [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BHgV.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BHgV.png)

Comment: Brett Champion, It works. Thank you so much! The important question now is: "Is there a way to specify colorbar on the legend from -4 to 1 and have colors from red to blue, respectively?" Also, how to reverse an Yaxis and specify X axis from 0 to 28.

Comment: Here's a dump of things to look up: (1) PlotLegends and BarLegend; (2) ColorFunction, ColorFunctionScaling, Blend, and ColorData; (3) ScalingFunctions; (4) PlotRange.  Combination of this site, subsections of the ListContourPlot docs, and individual docs pages (eg. ref/BarLegend) should be useful.

Comment: I have modified the code slightly. It is showing me nice results. But I am having hard time inversing the Y axis - I need Y ahis to change from 0 (top) to 180 (bottom). Brett Champion, would you know how to do it? Why ScalingFunction is not working? Thank you. SetDirectory["G:\\FGCI Staff\\Madyarova\\Mathematica\\Contour Plots"]; dataContour = Import["DataToPlot 90.csv"]; len = Length[dataContour]; legendwidth = 500; plotheights = 500; TemeratureChange = dataContour[[2 ;; len, 11]]; Zm = dataContour[[2 ;; len, 3]]; Xm = dataContour[[2 ;; len, 9]]; data1 = Table[{ Xm[[i]], Zm[[i]], TemeratureCh

Comment: @MaryMadyarova Please stop posting follow-up questions as answers. If you follow the link I have given in the comment below the question you will be able to merge your accounts and post comments under Brett's answer.